# Show docstring in an widget in Eclipse/pydev?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

In Eclipse/Pydev, the docstring is shown in hover and is disappeared after typing anything. Is there a plugin that can show the docstring in a widget that will keep shown until next docstring is triggered?

There's a similar feature called Object Inspect in spyder. It is very useful when using some unfamiliar packages.

Comment: Have you found a solution so far?

Comment: No- -|||@FranckDernoncourt

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no such feature right now. Please create a feature request in the tracker for that -- although even better would be a pull request ;) (shouldn't be hard as it'd be mostly creating a view which shows what the hover already shows).

Comment: Thanks. Is it still unimplemented? If not, I'll create a feature request.

Comment: It's still unimplemented, so, yes, please create a feature request -- bonus points if it could be a pull request instead ;)

Comment: Sounds good, I created a feature request, thanks! https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/757